# After flutter clean and build android module missing and show Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

Before Flutter clean
[image]

After Flutter clean and build (flutter pub get and run)
[image]
after flutter clean. flutter android native plugin module missing  .no issue found  in flutter doctor.

this is my code
https://github.com/lavahasif/fdserver

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89648

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

enough for the problem .But not that case.[[image]
after flutter clean the  and pub get command .no syntax
error or import error. then t try to build .i t show not plugin exist error . so  i delete the  java folder .that folder  contain the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java  file
which register the flutter module in native systerm. not the flutter run but show this error .module missing and show Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException.
so it is due to the android module not downloading.plugin register not auto generating